# How to fix the PG:Error: lo_unlink with Carrierwave-Postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, carrierwave

I'm currently using the **carrierwave-postgresql** gem on Rails 5.2. The issue I am having, is I cannot delete objects from my database that have the oid data-type/column attached to them. I tried to do a model.destroy_all, and then I received the error message below in my Rails Console

```
Model.destroy_all
(1.7) COMMIT
PG::Error: lo_unlink failed
from (irb):2
```

How do I edit my code to allow for the deletion of objects with attributes that have the oid column?